# Looping over a list and printing those elements of a string

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

So I need to create a function that iterates over a list of integers and print the characters of a string with those integers as indices. Something like this:

```
printString('123456789',[1,7,5,3])
2
8
6
4
```

i have this:

```
def printString(s,list):
    i=0
    resultString=str()
    for i in range(len(list)):
        resultString= s[list[i]]
        i=i+1
    print (resultString)
```

but it prints only the first character of the string, i guess there is a problem with the for-loop, i just can't find out what it is.

Any help will be useful! thank you

Comment: You can improve your loop itself: instead of `for i in range(len(list))` followed by `list[i]`, just use `for i in list`.  No need to create a range to produce indexes to then retrieve the item.  The loop construct does that for you.

Comment: Additional notes on your code:  the `i=0` serves no purpose, the value is overwritten when you reuse `i` in the loop. The line `resultString=str()` also serves no purpose since you reassign to `resultString` in the loop before you use the variable. Finally, the statement `i=i+1` also serves no purpose since `i` is overwritten by the loop construct.  So you can delete those three lines with no change to the outcome of your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `print(resultString)` so that it's inside the loop.

```
def printString(s,list):
    i=0
    resultString=str()
    for i in range(len(list)):
        resultString= s[list[i]]
        i=i+1
        print (resultString)
```

Additional but non-essential advice:

You don't need `i=0` or `i=i+1`, since the `for` loop already does the work of creating and incrementing the value for you.

```
def printString(s,list):
    resultString=str()
    for i in range(len(list)):
        resultString= s[list[i]]
        print (resultString)
```

You don't need `resultString=str()` because Python is perfectly happy to create a new variable in the middle of a function without any hints as to what its type should be.

```
def printString(s,list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        resultString= s[list[i]]
        print (resultString)
```

You don't necessarily need `resultString` at all since you're only using its value once.

```
def printString(s,list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        print (s[list[i]])
```

It's preferable to iterate over the elements of a list rather than its indices, if you don't have a specific need for the index.

```
def printString(s,list):
    for idx in list:
        print (s[idx])
```

Try not to use variable names that are identical to the names of built-in types.

```
def printString(s,seq):
    for idx in seq:
        print (s[idx])
```

Answer (score 2):

A function that results in this:

```
printString('123456789',[1,7,5,3])
2
8
6
4
```

Can be implemented in a multitude of ways, this is how i would do it.

```
def printString(input, indexArr):
  for i in indexArr:
    print(input[i])

printString('123456789',[1,7,5,3])
```

[Live Demo](https://repl.it/IRuG/3)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not appending all the result into the string, this will give you answer: `2864`

```
def printString(s,list):
    i=0
    resultString=str()
    for i in range(len(list)):
        resultString+=s[list[i]]
        i=i+1
    print (resultString)

printString('123456789',[1,7,5,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here. First, the `print` statement should be indented inside the loop. Second, even though it's innocuous here, you shouldn't manipulate `i` yourself, but leave the `for` loop to do it for you. And last, `list` is a horrible name for a variable, as it hides python's built-in list. Bring it all together, and you'd get something like this:

```
def printString(s, lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        resultString = s[lst[i]]
        print (resultString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your args as a test case:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def printString(strng, indexes):
    return ''.join((c for i,c in enumerate(strng) if i in indexes))
```

This uses `enumerate()` and a generator.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the print statement inside the for loop. It is only printing the last element because it gets overridden each time. You can also simply it as well

```
def printString(s,list):
resultString=str()
for i in range(len(list)):
    resultString= s[list[i]]
    print (resultString)
```